# Invert the ST_DWithin() function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, st-dwithin

Is it possible to perform a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo 
    JOIN bar
        ON ST_Dwithin(foo.geom, bar.geom, > 10);
        -- the > 10 means that I want to select everything that is further away then 10
```

I want to revert the `ST_DWithin()` function. I want to get all the `geometries`, that are farther away than 10 from `foo.geom`.

Is that possible? If not with the `ST_DWithin()` function, is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a correlated [`[NOT] EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   bar
  WHERE  ST_DWithin(bar.geom, foo.geom, <dist>)
);
```

Comment: Could you Explain the `WHERE NOT EXISTS ... SELECT 1`?

Comment: I added the link to the docs - they do a good job at explaining the mechanics, including the common `SELECT 1` convention.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
    JOIN bar
        on ST_Dwithin(foo.geom, bar.geom, 10)=FALSE;
```

Comment: This results in a (costly) cartesian product.

Comment: Doesn't the original SQL do the same? The title of the question was about inverting ST_Dwithin. Another option is to use `where ST_Distance(foo.geom, bar.geom) > 10`. But your answer really solves the problem instead of just answering the question.

Comment: Yeah I can't really just be literal in my answers if there's a misconception on the horizon. This _is_ literally the inverse (though a `NOT` would be more canonical), you are right. The issue with the result set here is the cartesian product of non-intersecting geometries - I described that better in one of OPs other questions so OP will likely know what is meant.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with a right joint

```
SELECT bar.* 
FROM foo 
RIGHT JOIN bar
    on ST_Dwithin(foo.geom, bar.geom, 10)
WHERE bar.geom IS NULL;
```

Or with a set operator :

```
SELECT *
FROM bar
EXCEPT
SELECT bar.* 
FROM foo 
JOIN bar
    on ST_Dwithin(foo.geom, bar.geom, 10);
```

(I couldn't test this requests)

Comment: Your first query needs to be a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: ST_Dwithin takes just one fixed distance and `> 10` gives a syntax error.

Comment: @user30184 Indeed, the correct syntax is ```ST_Dwithin(foo.geom, bar.geom, 10);```. I have update the answer.

Comment: @geozelot As I understand the question, the objective is to select individuals from the ```bar``` table not from the ```foo``` table, hence the use of the ```RIGHT JOIN``` and the ```bar.*``` after the ```SELECT```.